# Eavesdropping in VoIP. Any other software besides Ethereal?

Tags: voip

In school our professor demonstrated how the software Ethereal could be used to eavesdrop VoIP calls. That software no longer seems to exist since the webpages are no longer around.

What other software I should know about that could be used by employees on my internal network  to eavesdrop VoIP calls?

How big of a concern should I make this?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, this question is calling for product recommendations, or a list of products. This type of question is not really a good fit for SE sites - please see the [FAQ]. But btw, as one answer noted, Ethereal -> Wireshark.

Answer (score 3):

Ethereal was renamed [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) back in 2006 due to trademark issues.

Ethereal/Wireshark is just a packet capture tool with a GUI front end, there are many packet capture tools available. As to intercepting particular traffic, that would depend on particular network architecture and/or various attack methods that end up being a man in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Vomit was an old one I think Cain and Able has this functionality as well.